SqlDeveloper añade Final a un type as object
Escribí un código sencillo en Notepad++ y al ir a ejecutar la sentencia en SQLDeveloper, me añade de forma invisible (porque yo no veo donde queda esa sentencia, ya que en el código no) y lo sé porque hice una herencia de ese objeto y me pone que no se puede hacer herencia en objetos con final. El script que crea problemas es el siguiente:
CREATE TYPE Personal AS OBJECT (
    codigo INTEGER,
    dni VARCHAR2(10),
    nombre VARCHAR2(30),
    apellidos VARCHAR2(30),
    sexo VARCHAR2(1),
    fecha_nac DATE
   );
    
CREATE TYPE Responsable UNDER Personal (
    tipo  CHAR(1) ,
    antiguedad INTEGER
);

CREATE TYPE Zonas AS OBJECT (
    codigo INTEGER, 
    nombre VARCHAR2(20), 
    refRespon REF Responsable, 
    codigoPostal CHAR(5)
);

CREATE TYPE Comercial UNDER Personal (
    zonaComercial Zonas
);



En Responsable ya no puedo avanzar por lo de Final.

Yo no le veo el fallo. He cambiado de conexión, abierto y cerrado el gestor y nada. Es una conexión con un rol por defecto. No sé si añadirle un GRANT ALL privileges o algo así porque estoy atascada. No puedo comprobar el resto del código porque esa es la primera sentencia y hay varias herencias. Ah, el listener me está dando problemas (se apaga de vez en cuando), no sé si eso influye.


Qué tal si nos muestras todo el script completo?

Más allá del error. ¿Por qué haces un varchar2 de longitud 1?

Ahi os paso el script. Tengo más, pero nunca llegue a ejecutarlo porque era sobre los objetos. El varchar2 de longitud 1 es para poner m o f en sexo. No sé, me mandaron ponerlo así.

No es necesariamente que está añadiendo FINAL, sino que FINAL es el valor por defecto. ¿Ya intentaste colocar NOT FINAL?

¿porqué usa NotePad++ en lugar de escribir directamente en SQL Developer?
Es probable que el código de página de NotePad++ no sea igual al que maneja el SQL Developer que además está influenciado por el código de página del motor Oracle que esté conectado y la versión de Windows en cuanto idioma y región.
No lo uso, pero en archivos que he recibido de ese editor tiene por omisión usar el UTF-8 para grabar archivos.
Alguna vez me pasó también un error "extraño" y al mirar con un editor hexadecimal el archivo que generaron con el NotePad++ encontré que en lugar de un caracter "espacio" con código ASCII 32 había un caracter "espacio sin rompimiento" o "non-breaking space" o "hard space" con el código ASCII 160 (en el código de página ISO-8859; códigos de página 1250, 1251, 1252, 1253, 1254, 1255, 1256, 1257, 1258 para Windows; códigos de página 437, 850 y otros 8xx para DOS) y ahí Oracle al ejecutar la sentencia fallaba.
Espacio sin rompimiento o Espacio Duro
